How to use one or another variable to json marshal with same json tag
Supose I have the structure:
type foo struct {
    Name        string        `json:"name"`
    AgeYears    int           `json:"age" rlp:"optional"`
    AgeTimestamp time.Duration `json:"age" rlp:"optional"`
}

I want to return the var AgeYears OR AgeTimestamp into the json tag "age":
if isTimestamp{
    return &foo{
        Name:"Per",
        AgeTimestamp: 1342342554,
    } 
}else{
    return &foo{
        Name:"Per",
        AgeYear:30,
    } 
}

In the first case (isTimestamp==true) I'd like to receive:
{
    "name": "Per",
    "age": 1342342554
}

and in the second:
{
    "name": "Per",
    "age": 30
}

Is it possible in golang? How?

If you want to use structs, you will need multiple types.

The way your question is formulated: I do not understand what could set isTimestamp to true or false (note: plus you will note you mention a time.Duration go type, which technically isn't a timestamp), and I also do not understand if you want to produce a json string, read a json string, or both   (e.g: Marshal, Unmarshal or both). Can you give more details about your actual need ?

@LeGEC The server is in Go and handles requests from the client in Js, the server only sends responses, so it's a matter of marshaling structs to jsons. The bool isTimestamp is sent by the client in the request, since the client needs to be aware of the response it will receive. Sorry, I will try to be more clear next time.

would having one single type with a simple Age field work ? https://go.dev/play/p/wz-W-9P_Q9X


How to use one or another variable to json marshal with same json tag [?]

This simply isn't possible with encoding/json.
You either have to look for a JSON library that supports this, write your own, use different stucts with different tags or use e.g. a map.

Thanks, that's a useful answer because it points the way, I'm doing more research into using maps as an workaround to solve the problem
